# How to read a list of files from a folder using PHP?

Tags: php, file

I want to read a list the names of files in a folder in a web page using php.
is there any simple script to acheive it?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The simplest and most fun way (imo) is [glob](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

But the standard way is to use the [directory functions.](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: .".$file."<br />";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

There are also the [SPL DirectoryIterator methods](http://is.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php). If you are interested

Comment: I don't recommend Glob -- ever! It is extremely slow especially with many files.  I would use one of these: FilesystemIterator, DirectoryIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

Comment: `$dir = getcwd();` gets the current working directory.

Comment: What's the purpose of `!== false`?

Answer (score 19):

This is what I like to do:

```
$files = array_values(array_filter(scandir($path), function($file) use ($path) { 
    return !is_dir($path . '/' . $file);
}));

foreach($files as $file){
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: Needs one small fix: function($file) use ($path) { return !is_dir($path . '/' . $file);

Answer (score 16):

There is this function **scandir()**:

```
$dir = 'dir';
$files = scandir($dir, 0);
for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)
    print $files[$i]."<br>";
```

[More here in the php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Answer (score 3):

If you have problems with accessing to the path, maybe you need to put this:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = "/cv/"; 

// Open the folder
 $dir_handle = @opendir($root . $path) or die("Unable to open $path");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a glob. In this webpage there are good article how to list files in very simple way:

[How to read a list of files from a folder using PHP](http://domexception.blogspot.fi/2013/08/php-using-functional-programming-for.html)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard directory functions

```
$dir = opendir('/tmp');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    echo $file;
}
closedir($dir);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Check in many folders :**

Folder_1 and folder_2 are name of folders, from which we have to select files.

$format is required format.

```
<?php
$arr = array("folder_1","folder_2");
$format  = ".csv";

for($x=0;$x<count($arr);$x++){
    $mm = $arr[$x];

    foreach (glob("$mm/*$format") as $filename) {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a really simple way to do this with the help of the `RecursiveTreeIterator` class, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548504/2032235

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Names</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">

<form method='post' action='alex.php'>
 <input type='text' name='name'>
<input type='submit' value='name'>
</form>
Enter Name:
<?php

  if($_POST)
  {
  $Name = $_POST['name'];
  $count = 0;
  $fh=fopen("alex.txt",'a+') or die("failed to create");
  while(!feof($fh))
  {
    $line = chop(fgets($fh));
    if($line==$Name && $line!="")
    $count=1;
  }
  if($count==0 && $Name!="")
  {
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n$Name"); 
 }
  else if($count!=0 && $line!="") 
  { 
    echo '<font color="red">'.$Name.', the name you entered is already in the list.</font><br><br>';
  }
  $count=0;
  fseek($fh, 0);
  while(!feof($fh))
  {
    $a = chop(fgets($fh));
    echo $a.'<br>';
    $count++;
  }
  if($count<=1)
  echo '<br>There are no names in the list<br>';
  fclose($fh);
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.