# Insert blob into MySQL database upon local folder change

Tags: php, mysql

I have a folder of images which I would like to automatically add to a mySQL database as BLOB data.

HOW would I do this using PHP assuming database connectivity is working?

When I say automatically I mean if images are added to the folder upon loading a certain .php page the files are pushed to the db.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720751/how-to-read-a-list-of-files-from-a-folder-using-php