# Creating a dynamic image gallery using foundation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm still I new in php and js but I want to create a dinamic image gallery that should use all the images uploaded to one folder.

Could anyone give me an example of a php or js script that could make my gallery using foundation. Specificaly using [Clearing](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html).

All the images are in /img and the gallery should show all the images inside it. I dont need the whole solution cause I dont wanna look lazy I just dont know how to get the paths to all the images so I can create a loop i wich I put the paths in the foundation code:

```
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li><a href="path/to/your/img"><img src="path/to/your/img-th"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a "do this for me" free code resource. You need to show your attempt in PHP before asking for assistance

Comment: I asked for an example where I can get the paths so I can put them in a loop. And thats what I got in the answer below. 
Sorry if you misunderstood what I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to list files inside a directory. This is a trivial task in php. Someone already answered your question here.

[How to read a list of files from a folder using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720751/how-to-read-a-list-of-files-from-a-folder-using-php)

Once you have your array of filenames, simply loop over them using a for loop and output the required html as specified by foundation.

Here is documentation about for loops in PHP.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Good luck.